# Can't figure out where NullPointerException comes from

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to make an Android App that takes use of the built-inn SQLite database.
I have been struggling to make it work, and have tried several modifications.
When i launch the applications on mye phone (android 4.2) or emulator (Android 4.4) via eclipse i get several messages.
I don't know where the NullPointerExceptions comes from

```
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991): Process: com.example.julegaveliste2, PID: 991
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.julegaveliste2/com.example.julegaveliste2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at com.example.julegaveliste2.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
03-31 09:20:45.121: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  ... 11 more
```

These are the two java files inn the app:

```
    package com.example.julegaveliste2;



import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    Button knapp1;
    Button knapp2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        knapp1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Legg_Til);
        knapp2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Les_database);

        knapp2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            visliste();
            }
        });


       knapp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LagTabell(db.getWritableDatabase());
            }
        }); 

    }

    public static void LagTabell(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        ContentValues jul = new ContentValues();
        jul.put("person", "Ida");
        jul.put("gave", "blomst");
        db.insert("julegaveliste2", "person", jul); 
    }

    public void visliste()
    {   
        Cursor cursor=cursor();
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, cursor, new String[]{"person","gave"}, new int[]{R.id.person,R.id.gave},0);    
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        cursor.close();

    }

    private Cursor cursor()
    {
        return(db.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, person, gave FROM julegaveliste", null));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
        {
            super.onDestroy();      
            db.close();
        }

}
```

and:

```
package com.example.julegaveliste2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="julegaveliste2.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA=1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE julegaveliste2 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, person TEXT NOT NULL, gave TEXT);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("How did we get here?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this with your code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
DatabaseHelper db;
Button knapp1;
Button knapp2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

/*  Always initialize after setContentView      */
  db = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this); //This will also work

    knapp1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Legg_Til);
    knapp2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Les_database);

    knapp2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        visliste();
        }
    });
   knapp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LagTabell(db.getWritableDatabase());
        }
    }); 

}
```

Comment: I would not change it but database helpers don't need to be initialized after `setContentView` since they don't depend any UI.

Comment: before oncreate method you are passing the context in the databasehandler object which is wrong.your method needs context.you can only get the context after calling of oncreate method.after setting the view

Comment: Not outside / before `onCreate` but if all you need is a `Context` then *anywhere* inside `onCreate` is ok (I'd avoid putting code before `super.onCreate` though), only code that depends on the visual content (e.g. `findViewById`) *must* be placed after `setContentView`. `Context` is in fact attached to your activity right before the [system calls `onCreate`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2144) which makes the first line of `onCreate` the earliest place possible to use the context.

Answer (score 4):

```
 DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
```

you should move the `db = new DatabaseHelper(this);`, inside `onCreate()`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Cannot get the `Context` before, esp outside, `onCreate()`

Comment: There's no need to use `this.getApplicationContext()` - all it needs is `this`.